# Changing the units in blender breaks camera view

Tags: 3d-view, camera, scene, units

I changed the scale in blender so exporting to unity would be less of a hassle. I followed this tutorial to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnAb1w-Dmuc.

The problem is that after changing the scale, I cannot see anything through the camera. Even if I scale it up and point it directly in front of the model, nothing renders.

Comment: Make sure the camera's far clipping limit is big enough (properties editor > Camera > Lens > Clipping).

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! where is the far limit?

Comment: ok, I made it so it starts at 28 cm and ends at 33m. i positioned it directly in  front of the model. I originally positioned it by aligning the camera to view. I really can't work out why it is blank. Thanks for the responses!!!

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Sure! I've never done this before though so I don't know how.... where can I find out how to do it?

Comment: Just upload it to a hosting site like [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/), then put the link here

Comment: wow that was easy. here it is http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31499

Comment: ah no! I made a new file and for some reason this one works when I change the clipping plan to more than one metre... I was reluctant to send out the model I did (not that it's that great, haha). I'll keep fiddling with that one for a bit.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your file? (you can delete the bits which you don't want to release). It's possible it's some object setting, but if you delete the geometry of your model *in edit mode*, then the object settings will be preserved.

Comment: It's ok, you've helped me solve it now. I just wasn't using clipping effectively. Thanks so much for your help! If it happens again I'll send the actual model file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the *clipping distance* is too small:

[image]

One meter is the default size of the spaces in the grid, and in this case isn't large enough.

If you enable *limits* in *camera > display*, you can see a representation of the clipping distance in the 3D view, allowing you to see what might be wrong:

[image]